# Prolog as first programming language

Tags: prolog

I'm a computer engineering student but i've never programmed in my life (i've only studied physics, chemistry, control systems etc). Since I know a lot more about math than programming languages, and I'm studying logic right now on my own (i read it can be useful for artificial intelligence), i was thinking about learning Prolog as a first programming language. I tried to find some information about it on the internet but i couldn't really find much, all i discovered is that it's not really useful for landing a job but it can give you a different "mindset". Do you think it would be worth to learn it, or it would just be better learning something like C, Python etc?

Thank you!

Comment: It may be more fruitful to learn a functional programming language first, then the logic programming language after. Try Clojure for being near java and typeless (although there are still a LOT of concepts to swallow, go slowly), maybe even something used in in specialized numeric/stats settings like R or Julia. Unless you are into barely usable assembler, avoid C - I have an opinion on people using C in 2020 and it's not good, even (especially) if they are writing car MCU code (well, everyone goes through a hacker larval stage where C is appealing but one should grow out of it fast)

Comment: And yes, SWI Prolog is written in C (tradition, like vodoo rites, are hard to drop and once the train is rolling it is hard to stop). But Lambda-Prolog/Teyjus is written at least partly in OCaml, yay.

Comment: It depends upon your goals. If you're interested in programming for amusement, then you can pick anything you like. Prolog is fun to learn and play with. If you're looking for something that will give you high-demand programming skills, then you should pick a much more popular language. Declarative programming languages like Prolog (and there are very few others) are not at all common in industry compared to functional/imperative programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog is indeed a wonderful language, and it makes you think is a very differnt mode from other languages. As for making it a first, I think that's a bold move, and I suspect it'll make learning more languages a bit of a challenge. If your intent is to learn sofware engineering, I'm very sure you'll eventually learn another one.

I'd start with Python but, since you're curious already, learn it on the side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what do you mean with "it'll make learning more languages a bit of a challenge"? Why?

Comment: It'll tilt your understanding and intuition of what is "to program" to somewhere that's distant from "normal" programing languages, which is precisely why it's so liked but might get in your way. You might get frustrated by not having a bunch of tools at your disposal, it might be harder for you to agree with other languages mental models, etc. Don't be too scared, tho. This is just speculation from a random dude on the internet. Go have fun, explore, and learn! :)

Comment: Here's a notable example of where that happened: https://web.archive.org/web/20180923010353/http://hginit.com/00.html